# If exists multiple files

Tags: qt, cmake, resources

I want to export generated resource files for static library by means of `target_sources`:

```
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES "${PROJECT_NAME}.qrc")
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES "${PROJECT_NAME}_import.qrc")
endif()
set_property(SOURCE ${RESOURCES} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOGEN ON)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES} ${QM_FILES})
if (EXISTS ${RESOURCES})
    target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${RESOURCES})
endif()
```

If resource consists of only single file, then all is fine, but how to implement semantic `if(EXISTS ${FILE_LIST})` for list of files?

The intention of such a trick is to simplify the loading of resources from static libraries: generated `qrc_*.cpp` source files became a part of resulting executable file without need to call `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(*);`. The drawback of this approach is the need to rebuild all the subtargets twice.

Comment: "but how to implement semantic `if(EXISTS ${FILE_LIST})` for list of files` - Do that in `foreach()` cycle.

Comment: Maybe there is expression generator in `cmake`?

Comment: If you mean [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), they are intended mostly for things which cannot be achieved by normal means. Filtering existing files from the list (it is what you actually want, isn't it?) can be easy implemented by cycle over that list.